# Plotting von Karman-Nikuradse formula

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm trying to plot the friction factor for Darcy-Weisbach formula based on the von Karman-Nikuradse formula for subsonic compressible flow:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}=2 \log \left(\operatorname{Re} \, \sqrt{f} \right)-0.8 \tag{1}$$

So I defined a function using `NSolve`:

```
fKN[R_] := NSolve[(1/Sqrt[f] == (2*Log[R*Sqrt[f]] - 0.8)), f]
```

And tried to plot it using

```
Plot[fKN[R], {R, 10^5, 10^6}]
```

But I get a bunch of errors:

> NSolve::ifun
>
> General::stop

I would apreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: The eq. (1) and that in `NSolve` do not agree, what is the correct?

Comment: the latex one is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
fKN[R_] := NSolve[(1/Sqrt[f] == (2*Log[R*Sqrt[f]] - 0.8)), f][[1, 1, 2]] // Quiet
```

With this,

```
LogLinearPlot[fKN[R], {R, 10^5, 10^6}]
```

[image]

Note: in this case, `FindRoot` is actually faster than `NSolve`. I leave it to you to implement it, in case speed is important to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. would you please elaborate what `[[1, 1, 2]] // Quiet` does and maybe giving an example with `FindRoot `?

Comment: @Foad the output from `NSolve` is of the form `{{f->0.2}}`. To extract the number, we use `[[1, 1, 2]]`. Finally, `NSolve` alerts that it is going to ignore possible multi-valued and branches, and it is going to calculate only one solution; `Quiet` prevents this warning message (which is in fact irrelevant here),

Answer (score 7):

The exact solution can be obtained using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
sol = f /. Assuming[R > 0,
    Solve[(1/Sqrt[f] == (2*Log[R*Sqrt[f]] - 4/5)), f] //
     Simplify] // Quiet

(* {1/(4*ProductLog[-(R/(2*E^(2/5)))]^2), 
   1/(4*ProductLog[R/(2*E^(2/5))]^2)} *)
```

Using [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) to determine which solution applies to the region of interest

```
FunctionDomain[#, R] & /@ sol

(* {R < 0 || 0 < R <= 2/E^(3/5), -(2/E^(3/5)) <= R < 0 || R > 0} *)
```

Consequently, the second solution is desired

```
Clear[fKN]

fKN[R_] = sol[[2]];

LogLinearPlot[fKN[R], {R, 10^5, 10^6}]
```

[image]